# Silverlight 3 Datatemplate: Firing a button_click event

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, listbox, datatemplate, resourcedictionary

I have a datatemplate for a listbox stored in the ResourceDictionary. The template contains a button which when clicked should pass the listbox item to a seperate listbox

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxContentPresenterTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel Height="75" Width="100">
                <TextBlock x:Name="Surname" Text="{Binding Property1}" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" d:LayoutOverrides="Width"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="Firstname" Text="{Binding Property2}" Foreground="#FFC9C23E" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12" d:LayoutOverrides="Width"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Press" />     
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I don't know how to fire the event as adding it in the xaml as I normally would doesn't work here(presumably as it's a template).
Any help would be much appreicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataTemplate` is not the problem to subscribe to events. May be only if your `DataTemplate` is located in a separate resources file, so you have no rational place to place the event handler. If so you can make use of [Commands](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-4-How-to-Command-Control.aspx) (I believe this will work in version 3 too).

Comment: Hi Alpha, yes it is within a separate resource dictionary. I had looked at commands briefly but i'm pretty sure they're only in Silverlight 4.

Comment: @Chris: Well, msdn says ICommand is supported in Silverlight 3 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=VS.95).aspx